# How do you identify a foreign key constraint from its name?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, orm, coldfusion, sql-server-2012

Using Hibernate ORM against SQL Server 11 on ColdFusion 10.

I'm getting the error:

> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]The ALTER TABLE
>   statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK9E8E5409B9A80FE4". The conflict occurred in database "dbname", table
>   "dbo.TableName", column 'TableId'.

Which seems self-explanatory, except I have checked the relevant table in SQL Server Management Studio and don't find a foreign key constraint with that ID for that table, nor any related tables.

Is there a way to locate the constraint, e.g. by querying the database system tables?

*Update:* I was looking in the wrong system views - looking inside dbname.sys.foreign_keys I *do* see a bunch of foreign keys, but checking for the one mentioned in the error returns nothing. Is that the right place to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the sys.all_objects view, it's easier to query

```
select 
     sa.name as FKName
    ,so.name as TableName
from
    sys.all_objects sa
        inner join sys.objects so on sa.parent_object_id = so.[object_id]
where
    sa.[type] = 'F'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was after, but the constraint in the error isn't included in these results. :/

Comment: could it (the fk) be created by the ORM?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely ORM created, but should still be in the database? Anyhow, apparently hibernate does 'FK' + hash(table) + hash(column) to derive the name, so I've at least identified the problem table by matching the prefix; guess I just need to try figure out what's up with the ORM config now.